# Transport options to ensure net/http client connect via TLS 1.2

Tags: go

I have a go service that makes REST requests to an HTTP server that I don't control. A customer asked my to "confirm" that my service is connecting via TLS 1.2. Is that something that I can do in code?

Current code looks something like this:

```
request, _ := http.NewRequest("PUT",
    "https://example.com/path/to/endpoint",
    bytes.NewReader(json))

client := &http.Client{}

response, _ := client.Do(request)
defer response.Body.Close()

str, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
```

Based on a quick read of the docs I believe I need to use a `Transport` and build my client using that transport. Something like this:

```
tr := &http.Transport{
    ... some options here ...
}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
```

But I'm not sure what options I should set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the time of writing, Go will speak TLS 1.2 automatically if the server supports it.

[tls.ConnectionState](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#ConnectionState) reports various negotiated TLS parameters of a connection, including the protocol version.

To get the underlying TLS connection for an HTTP client it is easiest to set the `DialTLS` field of the `Transport` to a function that establishes and remembers the connection. Once the response arrived (but before you close the response body!), call [tls.Conn.ConnectionState](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Conn.ConnectionState):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    var (
        conn *tls.Conn
        err  error
    )

    tlsConfig := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig

    c := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DialTLS: func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
                conn, err = tls.Dial(network, addr, tlsConfig)
                return conn, err
            },
        },
    }

    res, err := c.Get("https://example.com")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    versions := map[uint16]string{
        tls.VersionSSL30: "SSL",
        tls.VersionTLS10: "TLS 1.0",
        tls.VersionTLS11: "TLS 1.1",
        tls.VersionTLS12: "TLS 1.2",
    }

    fmt.Println(res.Request.URL)
    fmt.Println(res.Status)
    v := conn.ConnectionState().Version
    fmt.Println(versions[v])

    res.Body.Close()
}

// Output:
// https://example.com
// 200 OK
// TLS 1.2
```

Comment: DialTLS Deprecated, please update your answer https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/)

> Package tls partially implements TLS 1.2, as specified in RFC 5246.

That beeing said I keep this function as a snippet to create the necessary configuration:

```
func NewTLSConfig(clientCertFile, clientKeyFile, caCertFile string) (*tls.Config, error) {
 tlsConfig := tls.Config{}

 // Load client cert
 cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(clientCertFile, clientKeyFile)
 if err != nil {
  return &tlsConfig, err
 }
 tlsConfig.Certificates = []tls.Certificate{cert}

 // Load CA cert
 caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile(caCertFile)
 if err != nil {
  return &tlsConfig, err
 }
 caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
 caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)
 tlsConfig.RootCAs = caCertPool

 tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()
 return &tlsConfig, err
}
```

After that you just need to initialize the transport:

```
transport := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig}
client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
```